# Jquery - possible variable click

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jquery.editinplace.js which is excellent but the problem I have it that I have multiple instances on a page - therefore need to somehow send a variable with it so it knows which row to update in the table

Can the ID be variable? e.g. #my_id123465, #my_id76543 then i can strip the #my_id in the backend PHP and be left with variable which tells me which row to update

So, example html for the page is currently: (there will be multiple of these)

```
<div id="my_notes" title="Click to edit">'.$item[comments].'</div>
```

And the jquery which is fired:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#my_notes").editInPlace({
    saving_animation_color: "#ECF2F8",
    url: '/pages/includes/edit_in_place.php',
        });

});
```

I'd almost like the code to be something like

```
$("#my_notes*").editInPlace({ // note the wildcard*
```

But that doesn't work

Comment: Possible but seems catchy. What are you trying to achieve? Can you elaborate a bit more precise?

Comment: @user1534664 yeah, each text to be edited is linked to a specific item a user has added - therefore the item has a 'comments' field and an item_id so i want to carry the item_id to the js

Comment: if you have multiple instances couldn't you use classes instead of the id, and then have the id to be the actual id you wish to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but could something like this work.

**Note i have changed the id to a class identifier if you have multiple instances**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".notes").editInPlace({
    saving_animation_color: "#ECF2F8",
    url: function(item){
         var id = $(item).attr("id");
         return '/pages/includes/edit_in_place.php?id=' + id;
},
        });

});
```

Comment: Figured it out same time you posted albeit a little simpler - it already has a callback of #element_id so all I had to do was as you said, change to class and add id <div class="my_notes" id="'.$item[item_id].'" title="Click to edit"> - will accept as soon as it lets me

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this:

```
$("div^='#my_notes'").editInPlace({ // etc
```

Have a look at the docs for this:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/